# Problems routing between two interfaces with iptables NAT

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, routing

I have a Linux server with three NICs:

- eth0: 1.2.3.4 (public IP)
- eth1: 5.6.7.8 (public IP)
- eth2: 10.0.0.1 (internal IP)

**I'm trying to have my Linux server act as a router between eth1 and eth2:**

```
Switch -> (eth2) -> Linux Server -> (eth1) -> Internet
```

I've gotten this to work when routing from eth2 to eth0, but not eth2 to eth1. When I try to route between eth2 and eth1, computers connected to the switch can ping the server at `10.0.0.1` but cannot access anything on the internet. These were the commands I tried (which worked when I swapped out eth1 for eth0):

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

I'm positive that eth1 has internet access because I can ssh into my server through 5.6.7.8, but I cannot seem to ping from it using `ping -I eth1 8.8.8.8`. I'm not sure if this is relevant to my iptables issue.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT `ip route` output:

```
default via 45.xxx.xxx.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 45.xxx.xxx.14 metric 100 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth2 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1
45.xxx.xxx.0/23 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 45.xxx.xxx.14
```

Comment: Your server is only going to use one default (Internet) route. To use the other Internet link, you will need to switch the default route or metric if you have two.

Comment: See, one default route, so any packets sent to any destination other than `10.0.0.0824` will only use that interface to reach the public Internet.

Comment: you need multiple default routes to use both internet links as @Ron Maupin says. See: https://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html

Comment: I added a new default route for the second link and it works now. Thanks @Ron Maupin and dmourati!